# Show all possible NullReferenceExceptions for property

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, code-analysis

I have decorated a public property with a `[CanBeNull]` attribute.

```
public class MyClass {
  [CanBeNull]
  public static string MyProp { get; set; }
}
```

Now I would like to see all possible NullReferenceExceptions regarding this property (e.g. `MyClass.MyProp.Length`).

I have enabled solution wide analysis. Now when I do right click -> "Inspect" -> "Code Issues in Solution" I get all kind of results and I can only filter by issue type, not by property. When I instead put the cursor on the property and do right click -> "Inspect This..." -> "Code Issues" I get some code issues of the containing .cs file but not the property.

The official docs ([1](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Analysis__Value_Analysis.html), [2](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Detect_possible_NullReferenceExceptions.html)) only show local detection of NullReferenceException. Is there a way (maybe outside of ReSharper) to find all issues regarding a certain property?

Note: I don't use C# 8, so no nullable and non-nullable reference types for me.

Comment: Right click property and "Find all references" is old working method.

Comment: If you don't want to allow `null` in your property, you should initialize it with a valid value and use a full property with a getter/setter and check in the set if the `value != null`.

Comment: @Sinatr This would give me dozens of useless results like `if (MyClass.MyProp != null) ...`

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen What if I'm not the one setting the initial value? What if some framework does (which is the case for me)? Sometimes the value is null (which is totally correct), sometimes not (also correct).